# Trying to get a specific color, and I can't get the desired result

Tags: javascript, css, html, web, colors

I am trying to take a regular video through a filter that looks like dark blue and light blue filter.

[image: dark blue and light blue filter].

The thing is it's on video, and I need it to be a mask (div on the video that changes the color). I have tried a couple of things but didn't get the desired result.

I tried to use `svg feColorMatrix`, and CSS filters. But I got a weird blue. If you have any other idea I will be grateful.

HAPPY new year!

```
filter: contrast(84%) brightness(31%) saturate(93%) grayscale(27%) hue-rotate(354deg);
```

Comment: You made a typo here: `saturatke(93%)` . need to write `saturate(93%)`

Comment: If you post the HTML as well, that will be more useful.

Answer (score 2):

This solution is purely based on HTML and CSS, 
Wrap your video with a container div and put another div before the video which will behave as an overlay, give it id something like "overlay", now css part

```css
#overlay{
position:absolute;
width:100%;
height:100%;
z-index:100;
background:blue;
opacity:0.5;
}
```

Other modifications you can make as per the output you want, but this will get you to the closest of your desired solution.

Comment: yes the problem is should be a gradient map, that means every light pixel become a bluelight pixel and the darks pixels will become black blue color (same as black and white only with dark blue and light blue)